# Изменение видимости div, при нажатии на input в обоих направлениях

Tags: html, javascript

Приветствую всех вошедших. Пробиваю одну тему, и ее аккуратно спрошу.

Представьте себе форма (достаточно простая), внутри формы 2 input-radio. Прошу помочь с 2мя вопросами:

Первое: Можно ли сделать такой JS, что бы при переключении input-radio скрывал div? Представьте, вы загрузили такую форму, и видите ее всю, нажили на переключатель - и часть формы скрывалась.

```
<form...>
<input type="radio" CHECKED>
<input type="radio">
<input type="text"...>    
<input type="text"...>

<div id="div_kotoriy_menayetsa">
<input type="text"...>
<input type="text"...>
<input type="text"...>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="ch1">
<input type="submit"...>

</form>
```

Второе: можно ли при загрузке формы сделать аналогичный, но противоположный данному скрипт, что бы изначально 2й (а не 1й) input-radio будет CHECKED, и соответственно, div хочется изначально скрыть?

upd. поправил маленькую ошибку

Comment: Исправьте imput на input. Вкратце - эти задачи легко выполнимы.

Comment: обновил. даже не заметил сразу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@frank, форму твою надо чуток изменить:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="switch-div_kotoriy_menayetsa" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="switch-div_kotoriy_menayetsa" value="0" checked="checked">
    <input type="text" >    
    <input type="text" >

    <div id="div_kotoriy_menayetsa">
    <input type="text" >
    <input type="text" >
    <input type="text" >
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" value="ch1">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

А вот сам скрипт (не чистый JS):

```
<!-- Да, вариант с jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('input[type=radio][name=switch-div_kotoriy_menayetsa]').change(function() {
    $('#div_kotoriy_menayetsa').toggle(
        $('input[type=radio][name=switch-div_kotoriy_menayetsa]:checked').val() == 1 ? true : false);
    })
    .change();

</script>
```

Можно и без заморочек с jQuery, но тогда или коряво будет, или этот простой скрипт пожирнеет.

У какого radio будет `checked="checked"`, тот и будет по умолчанию включен, соответственно, и div будет либо скрыт либо показан после загрузки страницы.

Comment: да, это не принципиально, с JQ или нет. спасибо

Answer (score 4):

> Первое: Можно ли сделать такой JS

Можно.

> Второе: можно ли при загрузке формы
> сделать аналогичный, но
> противоположный данному скрипт, что бы
> изначально 2й (а не 1й) input-radio
> будет CHECKED,

Можно.

Comment: Плюсую :) Хотел такой же написать ответ, но ограничился комментарием.

Comment: Весело. Кодом напугаете?

Comment: Нет не напугаем, какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Ты же написал, "можно ли" и получил ответ "Можно".

Кода ты как я знаю и уверяю не писал, но хочешь чтобы тут тебе его написали "как бы нечаянно в помощь", чтобы самому не думать, я не прав?

Что ты сам сделал для того чтобы твоя форма так работала? Ничего, кроме вопроса на данном форуме. Код на Jquery или на JS всего 1 строка.

("input[@name=''][checked]").val(); // так для справки.

\+ обернуть все это на событие онклик.

Comment: Сам думаю как это написать уже неделю. до этого 2 мои предыдущие темы здесь же на хэшкоде окончились ничем. Единственное что я узнал, что не нужно в форму таблицу совать. По поводу одна строка - т.к. сам пытался писать, узнал что все же не одна. Попробую с этим советом, что то еще сообразить

Answer (score 2):

```
var el_hide = $('#div_kotoriy_menayetsa');
el_hide.hide(); // скрываем необходимый элемент

$("input:radio:not(:checked)").click(function() {   
    el_hide.toggle('slow');

//  TODO: На Ваше усмотрение
//  $("input:radio:checked").attr("checked", false);
//  $(this).attr("checked", true);

})
```

P.S. Вопрос тривиальный и потому, чтобы не получать ответ подобно вышеприведённому, необходимо выработать в себе дисциплину самостоятельности.

Comment: к сожалению акцепт уже влепил, но на будущее учту и решение и совет по поведению

Comment: @frank Вот неплохой материал по селекторам для начинающих от "старателя" Шевчука.

[jQuery для начинающих. Селекторы][1]


  [1]: http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-selectors/